How to implement the view layer for a custom Akeneo PIM bundle?
I'm writing a (Symfony 4) bundle for Akeneo PIM Community Edition v5.
It's supposed to retrieve product stock data from an external instance (via REST API) and to display this data in the products list view and in the product detail view.
The backend part is basically done and also the bundle integration seems to be working, so I can trigger my service via a command and get the expected response (from an external API the service calls).
Now it's time to implement / extend the view layer. And I have no idea how to do this. The official documentation to the v5 (and also for all versions from v2 to current v7) is very, very slim... (Are there any howtos / tutorials? Please share any bit of info regarding this you can.)
How to implement the view layer for a custom Akeneo PIM Community Edition bundle?
